# Why Get-SmbOpenFile losses the lock when file still opened at remote

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, smb

I am using Get-SmbOpenFile, But surprisingly, it looses its connection and I can see that there is no lock even after couple of seconds later on the file any more, even it is still opened. I safely can remove that file on my server.

Why, this can be? I have to check opened .VHDX disk file connected with user and need to close them if they are still opened.

`Get-SmbOpenFile | Where-Object { $._Path -match '\\apvdp100\Profile\TestP1088\100.txt' }` returns nothing even the file is opened remotely.

`Get-SmbOpenFile | Where-Object { $._Path -match '100.txt' }` returns the object if i open the file remotely and check within a second.

So, I have two questions :-)

**So, what is the right way to search the file ?** ( above Fully qualified path doesnt returns the search result )

**Why the lock gets lost after couple of seconds later**